# La variabilité des adjectifs composés (compound adjectives)

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, accord

Issu de la page 36 de *Schaum's Outline of French Grammar* de Mary Crocker:

> If the first term of the compound adjective has an adverbial quality, it is invariable.
>
> des enfants **nouveau-nés** (*newborn children*)
>
> But:
>
> les fenêtres **grandes ouvertes** (*wide-open windows*)
>   des fraises **fraîches cueillies** (*freshly picked strawberries*)

Je suis égaré. Tous ces adjectifs composés me paraissent se distinguer par « an adverbial quality ». Or, pourquoi est-ce que les deux derniers exemples n'adhèrent pas à cette règle ?

Pourquoi n'écrit-on pas **grandes-ouvertes** et **fraîches-cueillies** ?

Comment: Je pense que par "compound adjective", l'auteur entend "adjectif composé", sous-entendu avec un trait d'union. C'est pourquoi "nouveau" reste invariable dans le premier cas, et que "grandes" et "fraîches" s'accordent dans les deuxième et troisième cas.

Comment: Les deux exemples n'adhèrent pas à la règle parce que ce sont des exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Si l'on regarde les recommandations de l'Académie Française, un nom utilisé comme adjectif s'accorde s'il représente effectivement l'objet qu'il qualifie.

Extrait du site de [question/réponses de l'académie française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/la-langue-francaise/questions-de-langue#13_strong-em-apposition-les-danseuses-toiles-regardent-des-films-culte-em-strong):

> Ainsi, on écrira Les danseuses étoiles regardent des films culte, car si l’on considère que les danseuses sont des étoiles (elles ont les mêmes propriétés qu’elles, elles brillent de la même façon), il est évident que les films ne sont pas des cultes, mais qu’ils font l’objet d’un culte.

Elle [préconise aussi l'accord des noms composés](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/la-langue-francaise/le-francais-aujourdhui) uniquement sur le second nom depuis 1990 (bien que les nouvelles règles du français préconisent l'accord des deux mots)

> — l’harmonisation du pluriel des noms composés avec celui des noms simples (un perce-neige, des perce-neiges, un garde-malade, des garde-malades...) ;

Partant de ces principes, il est parfaitement normal d'accorder **nouveau-né** avec **enfant** car les enfants sont en effet nouvellement nés.

Ainsi l'accord **des enfants nouveau-nés** est tout à fait correct puisque le singulier de **nouveau-né** existe. Il n'y a donc pas invariabilité dans ce cas.

Quand à l'accord suivant il est de rigueur d'accorder les adjectifs avec le nom qu'ils complètent, et je ne vois pas vraiment de contre exemple.

Concernant les deux exemples du livre, je n'ai jamais entendu parler de ces règles-là.  La différence se fait à mon avis sur le fait que *nouveau-né* est un mot composé alors que *fraîches cueillies* sont deux adjectifs et dans ce cas-là, l'accord des deux adjectifs est de rigueur, comme d'habitude.

Il semblerait cependant d'après [cette article](http://365jourspourapprendre.fr/accord-de-ladjectif-compose/) que d'autres règles encore plus complexes existent. Cependant, à part cas particulier comme **derniers-nés**, je pense qu'il faut aussi considérer que le français est une langue qui évolue, et selon les règles de français utilisées, on peut dans certains cas aboutir à des accords différents.

Comment: @LePressentiment j'ai essayé de rendre plus explicite l'accord des mots.